# Amazon Downloads - not music

Tags: amazon

I'm trying to download my virtual copies of some games from Amazon, but the amazon downloader is not compatible with Ubuntu I believe. I've searched for hours, but the only information I find pertains to music. I've tried pymazon but it works ONLY with music.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I believe you are correct.  Not sure what games you have that you are trying to download.  So depending on what you are doing, there are quite a few solutions.
If you are trying to play an HTML5 game, I'd suggest using Firefox, or for another easy solution you can use Chrome and the webapps store
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1053369?hl=en
Though most of those apps should work just fine in most other browsers (Firefox, Opera, Midori, Rekonq, etc...) I have tried some in Firefox, and can confirm they work well.

Now, if you are trying to download windows games, or android games, or iphone games, etc... they are specific to that platform (unless they are Java based).

So in a nutshell, Amazon's downloaders are not supported (including the instant video one) at the PRESENT time.  This may change, as the desktop and mobile climates are becoming more friendly to Linux and GNU (I separate the two because of Android being Linux, but not generally GNU)